# Regarding accessing the MIS server via the public IP from the internal interface

Tags: cisco-asa

I have port forwarded for my MIS server to be accessed from outside. From inside interface, i use 10.10.2.2:8000  to get access of the MIS. But, what i want right now is to be able to access the MIS via the public ip itself from the inside interface. ie, i want to access my MIS using A.B.C.D:8000 given that A.B.C.D is my public IP. Some friends suggested me this is called source nat. Please clarify .

Comment: You want to do hairpin routing. That depends on the router model. Which model do you have?

Comment: I have cisco asa 5515 x.

Comment: There are a few questions about this here. See  http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/25383/8499 particularly Ricky Beam's comment, and http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/6931/8499